# SQL Server Report Builder 3 using SQL IN operator with parameter not working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, reporting-services, split

I am attempting to filter a dataset in SSRS using the IN operator on a single column. When I add more than one value it fails.

For simplicity this is my SQL statement excluding other filters to focus on the new problem.

`SELECT * FROM vActivityDetailed WHERE Category IN (@Category)`

@Category is affected by an override expression under Dataset properties.

```
=Split(Parameters!Category.Value, ",")
```

Instead of using a multivalue parameter, I treat this as a single value and hope that by doing a split, the SSRS should execute like this.

C# - ASP.NET Code

```
string categoryString = "Expenses, Misc, Accounts-Receivable";
paramPayType.Name = "Category";
paramPayType.Values.Add((categoryString!= "" ? categoryString : null));
```

SSRS Final SQL Execution (Expected)

```
SELECT * FROM vActivityDetailed WHERE Category IN ('Expenses', 'Misc', 'Accounts-Receivable')
```

Since I've tested this directly on the SQL using SQL Server Management Studio, I know the above SQL should work since it returns records, but when applied in SSRS it fails with `An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)`

Comment: Have you tried to trace the SQL query text sent to your server through your application?

Comment: @niktrs Not sure exactly what you mean, because the query text is generated on the SQL Report Server and the only control I have in my ASP.NET application is sending the parameters. I can look at the value of each parameter before its send but after that, the most I can see is the error log on the SQL Reporting Server's database which shows each parameter sent, it looks correct in the error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter value in SSRS is an array of strings when multiple values are selected. The `Split` function takes a single string as its argument. You can't use `Split` with an array. SSRS with SQL Server handles the splitting of the values for you so you should be able to just pass the parameter straight through.

If you need to actually split the values for some reason, I would recommend using a custom SQL function. There are lots of examples if you run a search for that.

Comment: He's right you don't need to modify the parameter at all. Remove your "override expression" and it should work.

Comment: You are correct. I've been testing this for the past few hours and figured out no matter how I build the @Category parameter it would not work with the IN statement. I figured out using multivalue works flawless, now the issue is trying to figure out how to do all if no category is supplied. Thanks for the answer.